# Remove bottom space in display inline-block

Tags: html, css

I've looked everywhere and I have tried all possible solutions, but nothing.

I am making a scroll div with another divs inside. When I wrote "display:inline-block", each div add right and bottom margin. I can remove right margin (writing each div in the same code line), but also I need remove bottom margin. How can I do that?

Here my HTML and CSS code: https://jsfiddle.net/1ykbj8b4/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contenedor">
    <div class="imagen" style="background-color:blue"></div>
    <div class="imagen" style="background-color:green"></div>
    <div class="imagen" style="background-color:orange"></div>
    <div class="imagen" style="background-color:brown"></div>
    <div class="imagen" style="background-color:red"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {

    margin: 0;

}  

#contenedor {

    width: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: black;

}

.imagen {

    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `vertical-align: top;` on `.imagen`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#contenedor {
  width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.imagen {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="imagen" style="background-color:blue"></div>
  <div class="imagen" style="background-color:green"></div>
  <div class="imagen" style="background-color:orange"></div>
  <div class="imagen" style="background-color:brown"></div>
  <div class="imagen" style="background-color:red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed that. How can I select your answer as solution?

Comment: @Gabriel you're welcome. I think there is a checkmark by my answer that you can select?